# Coloring data in scatterplot 3d in r

Tags: r, colors, visualization, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize data using R and scatterplot3d.

I have loaded data and used

```
colors <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9" )
scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors, pch="X9")
```

X9 is label column in my dataset. it contains categories e.g "ab" , "cpu" , "imdb" and so on.

By documentation:

> color : colors of points in the plot, optional if x is an appropriate
>   structure. Will be ignored if highlight.3d = TRUE.
>
> pch: plotting  "character", i.e. symbol to use.

Yet I still get this error

> Error in scatterplot3d(output$X2, output$X6, output$X7, color =
>   colors,  :    length(color) must be equal length(x) or 1

I assumed I had to put color for every column in dataset , but creating such array where `length( colors ) = length(num of columns)` yields same error.

What is the right way to add colors?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think that you want `scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors[X9], pch=20)`  or maybe `scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors[output$X9], pch=20)`

Comment: @G5W this printed empty graph

Comment: Both versions were empty?

Comment: @G5W both of them printed empty box

Comment: I updated info , i acciedntly mistaken the value of lebel collumn, its not A B and C  string e.g "ab" , "cp" , "ib" , "cpu"

Comment: OH!  it's a string.  Try, `scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors[as.factor(output$X9)], pch=20)`

Comment: it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have fewer colors than data points.  You must select one color for each point.  Since X9 seems to be a string, you can use `as.factor` to assign a unique number to each value.

```
scatterplot3d(output$X2,output$X6 , output$X7 , color=colors[as.factor(output$X9)], pch=20)
```